# Changing IE Homepage

Tags: java, windows, internet-explorer, applet, registry

I'm trying to change IE homepage with modifying registry. I've done this succesfully with a bat file;

```
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\MAIN" /V "START PAGE" /D "http://www.stackoverflow.com/" /F
```

I also want to do this on java, tried this but it doesn't work.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.applet.Applet; 
import java.awt.*; 

class test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("REG ADD 'HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main' /V 'Start Page' /D 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/' /F");
      } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Error ocured!");
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: errors? logs? problems? explain what happened.

Comment: What error did you get?

Why did you import awt and Applet? They are absolutely not required...

If this code however really runs in an applet, you will not be able to accomplish what you are up to: there is no way an Applet could write the registry (unless of course there is  a major security breach in the browser...).

Comment: `reg` is not an executable. It is an internal command of the `cmd` shell.

Comment: No errors and nothing happens when I run this.

Comment: @ppeterka *"there is no way an Applet could write the registry (unless of course.."* ..it is trusted).

Comment: @AndrewThompson wow, I never ever even thought such a thing as trusted applet existed... Thank you for enlightening me... I feel a bit shaken though, as the last thing I want is to have an Applet control anything deeper than an awt.Canvas...

Comment: @ppeterka  Don't worry too much.  An applet needs to be digitally signed, and ***accepted by the user when prompted*** before it becomes trusted.  The type of 'trust dialog' can be seen at this [properties applet at my site](http://pscode.org/prop/all.html?prop=java.specification.version%2Cjava.version%2Cjava.vm.version%2Cjava.runtime.version).  The first 3 properties are available to all applets, but only trusted applet can get the last one.  If you refuse the trust dialog and are running an Oracle JRE, it might still load the applet, but sand-box it as usual.

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Thanks for explaining, I'm not worried at all, just shaken about the fact that someone other than Microsoft thought giving control to a browser is moving humanity forward...

Comment: @ppeterka Yes, Sun's decisions re. what a small GUI embedded in a web page should be about often leave me perplexed.  Of course, that did not stop me from writing the little properties applet that leveraged one of those decisions.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson : after all, a door that exists is a door to be opened, ain't it?

Comment: @ppeterka  Absolutely.  I live in a (dream) state, where "Because damnit, we had the technology" is a valid defense for just about anything.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
CMD /C REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\MAIN" /V "START PAGE" /D "http://www.stackoverflow.com/" /F
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not via the registry, but it does the job. You can use this code (with Firefox compatibility too):

```
function setHome() {
    if (document.all) {
        document.body.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)';
        document.body.setHomePage('http://url_of_page.com');
    } else if (window.sidebar) {
        if(window.netscape) {
            try {
                netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
            }
            catch(e) {
                alert("this action was aviod by your browser，if you want to enable，please enter        about:config in your address line,and change the value of     signed.applets.codebase_principal_support to true");
            }
        }
        var prefs = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1'].getService(Components. interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
        prefs.setCharPref('browser.startup.homepage','http://url_of_page.com');
    }
}
```

Then execute the function with:

```
<a href="javascript:setHome();">make your home page</a>
```

Source: [HERE](http://bluewhalelabs.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/javascript-function-to-set-a-web-page-as-home-page-for-ie-and-firefox-compatible/)

Comment: *"It's not.."*  ..Java, Jim.  At least, not as we know it.